# UIRemoteNotificationType invalid conversion

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use this fairly standard line of code in my app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

But am receiving the follow error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'UIRemoteNotificationType'
```

It works if I only use one of the notification types but fails every time if I try and use more than one. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably using Objective-C++, which implicit conversion from `int` to an enum is disallowed.

Try to add an explicit cast:

```
[… registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | …)];
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast the result as UIRemoteNotificationType:

```
(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)
```

This way the method got what it is expecting.

Comment: This was correct but I accepted KennyTM's answer as it provided the detail why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: This will solve ur problem.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```