# cannot initialize a parameter of type UIRemote NotificationType with an rvalue of type int

Tags: ios, ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];` to register remote push notificatioin, an error occurs saying `cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UIRemoteNotificationType' with an rvalue of type 'int'`, does anybody know why? thank you.

My project's environment: Xcode 4.2 + iOS 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584453/uiremotenotificationtype-invalid-conversion

Comment: I'm very happy and also thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should cast it explicitly to `UIRemoteNotificationType`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: @jbat100 Thanks! It worked for me but can you please explain why we need casting here?

Comment: @Harsh I would say the reason is that once you perform a bitwise operation on the enum, e.g (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound), the result of the operation is the type that the compiler uses to represent the enum (which depends on the range of its values), usually some integer type. I'm not sure why it doesn't happily cast it back implicitly to UIRemoteNotificationType in this case though.